# User deleted and reposted his answer due to heavy negative reputation

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I recently came upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427846/android-toast-maketextthis-not-working-for-appcompatactivity#39427902) post, and a user posted an incorrect answer, so it got -3 rep. He deleted the answer, then posted it again to remove the rep. What do we do in cases like this?

Comment: DV it again? is it still the same answer?

Comment: It is usually a good idea to notify the user to let him know the behavior is discussed at meta.  Best way to teach him.  Done.

Comment: I believe also that deleting a downvoted question does not stop it from being taken into account by the ban filter.

Comment: @KevinL Yes, it was the exact answer.